# DbContext and concurrency in testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, concurrency, entity-framework-core

I have a few tests that I would like to run all in parallel to speed up testing. The tests when run individually works fine, but throw concurrency-related errors when running in parallel. I have a Tests base class that has a few protected variable that is set in the constructor then referenced in each test method. I also have a static Seeder Class whose methods are called in the constructors of the base classes, and its purpose is to just add some static test data. When run in parallel, I can see that each instance of the dbcontext has different values, meaning that some functions ran successfully and are not just overwriting the same in-memory database over and over? However, everytime when it hits SeedTaskings, it would error out on the dbcontext.Quest.Addrange() line and says "Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access" or "the dbcontext is already tracking an entity". I am really confused as to why, tho it seems like each test method has its own in-memory database(because of different values shown in each DbContext), it would throw errors that indicate that they are all trying to write to the same DbContext?

```
[assembly: Parallelize(Scope = ExecutionScope.MethodLevel)]

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Tests
    {
        protected AppUser Admin;
        protected AppUser Analyst;
        protected AppUser CaseManager;
        protected ApplicationDbContext DbContext;
        protected AppUser DeactivatedExaminer;
        protected AppUser Examiner;
        protected IMapper Mapper;
        protected UserManager<AppUser> UserManager;
        protected RoleManager<AppRole> RoleManager;
        protected Case CaseOne, CaseTwo, CaseThree, CaseFour;

        protected Tests()
        {
            DbContext = MockDbContext();
            Mapper = MockAutoMapper();
            UserManager = MockUserManager(DbContext);
            RoleManager = MockRoleManager(DbContext);
            Admin = UserManager.FindByNameAsync("administrator1").Result;
            Examiner = UserManager.FindByNameAsync("examiner1").Result;
            DeactivatedExaminer = UserManager.FindByNameAsync("deactivatedexaminer1").Result;
            CaseManager = UserManager.FindByNameAsync("casemanager1").Result;
            Analyst = UserManager.FindByNameAsync("analyst1").Result;
            DbContext.Seed(UserManager, RoleManager, "Testing");
        }
```

Content of the MockDbContext Function

```
        protected static DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> CreateNewContextOptions()
        {
            // create a fresh service provider, therefore a fresh inmemory database instance
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            // Create a new options instance telling the context to use an in memory
            // database and the new service provider
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider)
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            return builder.Options;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Mocks a standalone in-memory database for test purposes
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Functional ApplicationDbContext instance</returns>
        private static ApplicationDbContext MockDbContext()
        {
            var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(CreateNewContextOptions());
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            return dbContext;
        }
```

The actual test class and methods, errors out inside SeedTemplates

```
[TestClass]
public class DatabaseJsonQueryTests : ControllerTests
{
    private readonly DatatableJsonQueryController _controller;
    public DatabaseJsonQueryTests() : base(Roles.CaseManager)
    {
        _controller = new DatatableJsonQueryController(DbContext, UserManager, Mapper)
        {
            ControllerContext = ControllerContext,
            TempData = TempData
        };
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void PopulateWorkflows()
    {
        DbContext.SeedTemplates();
        DbContext.SeedInstances(100);
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    public void ActiveCaseTable()
    {
        var order = SetOrder(1, true);
        var result = _controller.CaseTableQuery(_caseColumns, order, 1, 0, 10, false, new CaseFilterModel())
            .Value.TryTypeCast<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        var data = result["data"].TryTypeCast<IEnumerable<CaseRowModel>>();

        Assert.AreEqual(DbContext.Cases.Count(c => c.Status == CaseStatus.Active), data.Count());
    }
```

Here is where it would error out

```
    public static void SeedTemplates(this ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext.Workflows.Any()) return;
        dbContext.SeedSubtaskings();
        dbContext.SeedTaskings();
        dbContext.SeedProcesses();
        dbContext.SeedWorkflows();
    }
    public static void SeedSubtaskings(this ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        dbContext.SubQuests.AddRange(MakeBedSubs);
        dbContext.SubQuests.AddRange(WarmupSubs);
        dbContext.SubQuests.AddRange(JoggingSubs);
        dbContext.SubQuests.AddRange(MakeBreakfastSubs);
        dbContext.SubQuests.AddRange(EatBreakfastSubs);
        dbContext.SubQuests.AddRange(CleanSubs);
        dbContext.SubQuests.AddRange(LeaveSubs);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static void SeedTaskings(this ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _makeBed = CreateQuest("Make Bed", ServiceTier.One, "Make bed is goooood", MakeBedSubs, 1);
        _warmup = CreateQuest("Warm Up", ServiceTier.One, "Warm up is goooood", WarmupSubs, 2);
        _jogging = CreateQuest("Jogging", ServiceTier.One, "Jogging is goooood", JoggingSubs, 3);
        _makeBreakfast = CreateQuest("Make Breakfast", ServiceTier.One, "Make breakfast is goooood", MakeBreakfastSubs, 4);
        _eatBreakfast = CreateQuest("Eat Breakfast", ServiceTier.One, "Eat breakfast is goooood", EatBreakfastSubs, 5);
        _clean = CreateQuest("Clean", ServiceTier.One, "Clean is goooood", CleanSubs, 6);
        _leave = CreateQuest("Leave", ServiceTier.One, "Leave is goooood", LeaveSubs, 7);
        dbContext.Quest.AddRange(new []{ _makeBed, _warmup, _jogging, _makeBreakfast, _eatBreakfast, _clean, _leave });
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Static collections inside the static seeder class as member variables

```
    private static readonly List<SubQuest> MakeBedSubs = new() 
    { 
        new("Fold the blanket") { Finalized = true },
        new("Fold bed sheets") { Finalized = true },
        new("Put everything on the bed") { Finalized = true },
    };
    private static readonly List<SubQuest> WarmupSubs = new() { ...just like the above}
    a few more private static List<SubQuest> just like above

   private static Quest MakeBed, Warmup, Jogging, EatBreakfast, MakeBreakfast, Clean, Leave;
    private static Process Wakingup, Excercise, Cooking, Cleaning, Leaving;
    private static Workflow MorningRountine;
```

Content of the CreateQuest static method,Quest to SubQuest is a many-to-many, and the QuestSubQuest object is the bridge table if you will

```
    private static Quest CreateQuest(string name, ServiceTier serviceTier, string description, List<SubQuest> subs)
    {
        var i = 1;
        var quest = new Quest(name, serviceTier.ToString(), description)
        {
            Finalized = true,
            QuestSubQuest = new List<QuestSubQuest>(),
        };
        subs.ForEach((e) => {
            quest.QuestSubQuest.Add(new(quest,e, i++));
        });
        return quest;
    }
```

Comment: @Charlieface I understand that DbContext is not thread-safe. I am still relatively new, doesnt each test class here creates its own dbcontext and a separate in-memory database? If i put a breakpoint in the base constructor, the breakpoint would be hit as many times as the # of test methods continuously before the next line is executed, which leads me to think that different instances of dbcontext and in-memory databases are created. Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Hum you're quite right I didn't read the code properly. Perhaps one of the objects has an property or method which accesses the context and modifies it?

Comment: Can you add the code for CreateQuest?  It also isn't clear what values like "MakeBedSubs" is and where it comes from. If these are static collections of entities you could be running into issues if they are being associated with multiple DbContext instances.

Comment: @StevePy I will definitely add them on here. And you are quite right. These are static collections of entities.

Comment: @Charlieface Like Steve Py pointed out, these collections that are being added to the DB are static collections which may be the cause. Thanks

Comment: @StevePy I have just added them to the end. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, that would be the lead suspect. EF works with references so each DbContext will need to be responsible for loading references for the SubQuests lookup lists that are being referenced in those QuestSubQuest instances being created.

Comment: @StevePy OMG, you are a life savor. I have been stuck on this for a day. For some reasons I cant get test to run on my home computer. Ill let you know if that solves the problem tomorrow when i get to work. I think that is it tho. Thanks a lot

Comment: @StevePy that did it..changing it to a non-static class with non-static variables. This is why the Random class needs to be instantiated, I see. I never understood thread-safe until now I guess. Thanks a lot.